# How to make partially visible app that works over another app

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen apps like `Gamekiller` and `Scramble Cheat` that shows partially over another app like a shadow and the touch events over them actually works over the background app.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Just supply this attribute to the activity in your manifest file **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"** and set your relative layout background to transparent.

Comment: but these apps kinda hangs at the corner when you collapse them and expands by click on that corner icon.

Comment: It will not hang in this case

Comment: Then how can I do that. Just look at those apps .

Answer (score 1):

NO don't use transparent background use a service like this example it explains it well and could take you in the right direction.
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Or you could use standout.
https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

I haven't tried standout yet but it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can add own view to screen (`WindowManager.addView`). But in need permission `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

Or, better, create custom dialog with custom `LayoutParams`. Must important - set `type` to `TYPE_PHONE` or `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

It display over other app.